# plotting an interactive graph for a pandas dataframe using plotly-dash is throwing callback error updating output

Tags: python, pandas, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a basic interactive plot for a timeseries dataframe I have. I have read the data into a data frame `df`. It has `datetime` as index and two other colums `category` (has 3 unique values), `count`.
Now, I'm trying to plot an interactive graph using plotly-dash with following features

1. It will have a input box where the user should enter the `category` value for which they want to see the plot for
2. If the value they entered is in `df['category'].unique()` it will return the timeseries plot corresponding to that particular category. Else It will throw an error

This is the code I have written for it

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children = [
    html.H1(children='Dash trail'),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input_id',value='',type='text'),
    dcc.Graph(id='inflow_graph')
])

@app.callback(
[Output(component_id='inflow_graph',component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='input_id',component_property='value')])
def update_graph(input_text):
    if input_text in df['category'].unique():
        dff = df[df['category']==input_text]
        fig = px.line(dff, x=dff.index, y=dff['count'],title='count for selected category')
        return fig
    else:
        return 'Enter the correct category value'
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,use_reloader=False)
```

It is throwing the following error

```
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback ..inflow_graph.figure.. is a multi-output.
Expected the output type to be a list or tuple but got:
Figure({
    'data': [{'hovertemplate': 'ds=%{x}<br>ticket_count=%{y}<extra></extra>',
              'legendgroup': '',
              'line': {'color': '#636efa', 'dash': 'solid'},
              'mode': 'lines',
              'name': '',
              'showlegend': False,
              'type': 'scattergl',
              'x': array([datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0), ....(and so on my full dataframe)
```

I didn't understand where I'm calling back multiple outputs. How do I resolve this error?

Edit: Adding sample data here

```
            Category Count
date(index) 
2020-01-03    A       30
2020-01-03    B       50
2020-01-04    C       14
2020-01-04    A       16
2020-01-04    B       40
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your data in order to make your code reproducible.

Comment: Added the sample data in the edit

Answer (score 2):

In `@app.callback()` you put a list of Outputs, containing a single element. If you do so, you'll need to return a list as well, so `return [fig]` instead of `return fig`.

However, you don't need to have the lists at all, so your callback decorator can simply look like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('inflow_graph', 'figure'),
    Input('input_id', 'value'))
def update_graph(input_text):
```

Note how I also dropped the `component_id` and `component_property` keys for brevity, since they are also not needed in current versions of Dash (they are not wrong however).

There is another problem in your callback though: You return a string in the `else` case, but `inflow_graph.figure` will expect a Figure object or dictionary. You can fix this by returning an empty dictionary (`return {}`).